# Is FindFirst() buggy under XE2/Firemonkey using iOS?

Tags: ios, delphi, freepascal, firemonkey

For an iPhone Firemonkey application I am storing files (images) in the 'tmp' folder and using them in my application.  I want to be able flush the cache by deleting say all of the '.jpg' files on demand, but I cannot seem to programatically match them in a **FindFirst()** call.

I am using a simple **FindFirst() / FindNext() / FindClose()** loop to list (and delete) the contents of a folder.

Under windows the code works perfectly.  The same application under iOS (iPhone) is always returning a value of -1 (error) for the **FindFirst()** call, and **SearchRec.Name** is blank.  I have tried using various file patterns including '*.*' with no success.

I know the files exist because I can read and write to them (under both iOS and windows) without error, and their contents is correct.  A **FileExists()** check also returns True.

Also, if I specify a file pattern with no wildcard, to check for a known file (which really isn't the point of a **FindFirst()** call), the call never returns (again this is fine under windows)!

Has anyone had any success with this under iOS and can offer any thoughts?

Thanks,

EDIT:  Code snippet as requested which demonstrates the problem.
Note: _sFolderName contains the cache folder name which I have confirmed is definitely correct.

```
function GetCacheFileList : string;
var
  iResult: integer;
  sr: TSearchRec;
  sPath,
  sTemp: string;
  sFilename : TFilename;
begin
  sTemp     := '';
  sFilename := _sFolderName + '*.jpg';
  //
  iResult := FindFirst(sFilename, faAnyFile, sr);  // ALWAYS RETURNS -1 under iOS
  while (iResult = 0) do
  begin
    sTemp := sTemp + sr.Name + sLineBreak;
    iResult := FindNext(sr)
  end; { while }
  //
  FindClose(sr);
  Result := sTemp
end;
```

Comment: Could you post some code to reproduce the issue? Did you use the specific POSIX path separator '/' instead of '\'? I'm not convinced the 'tmp' folder is the place to implement a cache. Did you try in another folder?

Comment: Hi AB, yes the path separators are correct (for both windows and iOS).  Have since discovered there is a /library/caches/ folder which I am now using, but same result.  I will post some code above, but it is pretty unremarkable stuff.  I have also been informed that there was a bug in FreePascal's file handling in iOS which *may* be fixed in 2.6.0rc1, which I will try in the next day or so when I get back to it.  Thanks for your suggestions (+1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed under XE2 update 3

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well FindFirst, etc are supported on non-Windows platforms, but I do recall someone from the Delphi team saying once that the routines in the `IOUtils` unit are specifically designed to make file I/O work right for cross-platform coding.  Have you tried using the file search methods on `TDirectory`?

Comment: Nice thought (+1), however as with a lot of the newer Delphi features, they aren't really supported cross platform since, in the case of iOS, the compilation takes place under XCode using the free pascal compiler, which doesn't support these features.

Comment: Findfirst works fine in general on FPC. But I don't use iOS, so it might be something iOS specific. I don't know if iOS supports ktrace/strace/truss like functionality, but that would be my thing to try. Afaik most of the pseudo OOP routines in recent delphi's call the old procedural versions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Delphi XE 2 is shipped with headers from iOS SDK, but you can generate them for FreePascal([read here](http://web.me.com/macpgmr/ObjP/Xcode4/ObjP_Part3.html)). And then use this method via standard API:

```
{$modeswitch objectivec1}

uses
  iPhoneAll, CFBase, CFString;

type
  TFileList = record
    Count : Integer;
    Items : array of String;
end;

procedure file_Find( const Directory : String; var List : TFileList; FindDir : Boolean = FALSE );
  var
    i           : Integer;
    fileManager : NSFileManager;
    dirContent  : NSArray;
    path        : NSString;
    fileName    : array[ 0..255 ] of Char;
    error       : NSErrorPointer;
    isDirectory : Boolean;
begin
  fileManager := NSFileManager.alloc().init();
  path        := NSString( CFStr( PChar( Directory ) ) );
  dirContent  := fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath_error( path, error );
  List.Count  := 0;
  fileManager.changeCurrentDirectoryPath( path );
  for i := 0 to dirContent.count() - 1 do
    begin
      if FindDir Then
        begin
          if ( fileManager.fileExistsAtPath_isDirectory( dirContent.objectAtIndex( i ), @isDirectory ) ) and ( not isDirectory ) Then continue;
        end else
          if ( fileManager.fileExistsAtPath_isDirectory( dirContent.objectAtIndex( i ), @isDirectory ) ) and ( isDirectory ) Then continue;

      SetLength( List.Items, List.Count + 1 );
      FillChar( fileName[ 0 ], 256, 0 );
      CFStringGetCString( CFStringRef( dirContent.objectAtIndex( i ) ), @fileName[ 0 ], 255, kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
      List.Items[ List.Count ] := PChar( @fileName[ 0 ] );
      INC( List.Count );
    end;
  fileManager.dealloc();
end;
```

This function returns record TFileList with array of all found files(or directories). Then you can just pars names of files and do something with jpg-files.

Comment: Hi Andru,
Thanks for your comment and the link to Phil's website (which I had previously bookmarked - he seems to be the go-to man on FPC and iOS).  My first choice is to use the standard pascal calls as I ultimately want as much platform independence as possible (for windows and *possibly* android support in say XE3).  Using cocoa (with a bit of conditional compilation) as you have described however is my fallback position and quite possibly one which I will go with.  Appreciate your assistance (+1).